# PHP SoapClient __soapCall()

Tags: php, soap

I'm new to this PHP SOAP.(SoapClient)
I'm kind of confused as to when to use `_soapCall();` and when to use the function i got from `_getFunctions();`

Response i got from  `__getFunctions()`
`EstimationResponse 

Estimation(Estimation $parameters)`

What is correct?
`$client->__soapCall("Estimation", $params);`
or
`$client->Estimation($parameters);`
I have tried both but resulted to nothing or NULL
When can i use what ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It does not matter.

The SoapClient provides an interface that magically allows to call every SOAP method found in the WSDL as a method of the instantiated client. But this magic internally is mapped to a call to `__soapCall`.

Comment: I appreciate your answer. Does it mean i the result of the following three methods are the same ?

Comment: I appreciate your answer. I need to work on these magic methods. The only php magic methods i know are the getters and setters.

Comment: In fact, there isn't really very much magic around on the outside of the SoapClient object. You will probably stumble upon `__call`, which I suppose is used internally to forward calls to `__soapCall`. Also, a lot more internal calls to various functions take place that allow to intercept the ongoing SOAP request at certain stages, but this is rarely used.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of `__soapCall` is to allow more flexibility in how you can call functions. Since the arguments to and return from a magic method are only what the SOAP service itself defines, they cannot include information meant for the PHP SOAP library itself.

For instance, in the absence of a WSDL file, you can still create a `SoapClient` object, but PHP will not be able to map "magic" functions to the appropriate verbs. `__soapCall` includes an `options` argument which allows you to manually specify the details which would have been provided by the WSDL.

Another thing which is tricky with the "magic" methods is sending and receiving "SOAP headers" - out-of-band information such as authentication or session details. These can be handled via the 4th and 5th arguments to `__soapCall`.

In short, if you can do what you need to with the magic methods use them; if you find you're hitting a limitation, check if calling `__soapCall` directly can help.

Comment: Thanks @IMSoP. I need to read more about these magic methods.